# Unrecognized structure of "so... that"

Tags: grammar-identification

I came across this sentence:

> Was gibt es denn so Spannendes, dass du mich extra morgens um acht anrufst?

This seems to be the structure similar to English: "... so adj/adv that + clause". I think its meaning can be translated as "*What is that, that is so exciting that you call me at 8:00 in the morning?*"

But clearly to me, **Spannendes** is not merely an adjective or adverb, due to postfix "es". If it were just adjective, there would be a "to be" nearby. If it were adverb, there would be a verb nearby. (here "geben" is not appropriate).

In German, we can replace "Adject + Noun" with simply "Adjective" (similar to english, e.g. "the rich", "the poor"), and capitalize that adjective.

But *which noun does this adjective modify?* It could be implied as "etwas" but then the whole grammar structure of the sentence is incorrect.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following. "Spannendes" clearly is a noun (as indicated by capitalization). In fact, it is a nominalized adjective and would be translated as "something exciting/fascinating". Note that your example is rather colloquial language.

Comment: *Etwas* isn't implied, but it's literally in there: *Was …*

Comment: @Janka I thought *Was* here is rather similar to "What" in English.

Comment: Only similar. Not the same. *Es gibt etwas Spannendes. — Was gibt es Spannendes?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Spannendes* is an adjectival noun; in the neuter singular, these denote things.

> Sie lese nur **Spannendes** (=spannende Dinge), Geschichten über alte Bankiersfamilien oder über die Anfänge des Währungsfonds. (*Zeit*, 12.11.2015, via [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r))

These adjectival nouns frequently stand in apposition to an indefinite pronoun:

> etwas Neues, viel Interessantes, wenig Wichtiges, …

However, when they stand in apposition to a question word *was*, they have to be split from it.

> Ich habe gestern **(et)was Spannendes** gelesen. (*indefinite pronoun*)
> *I read something exciting yesterday.*
>
> **Was** hast du gestern **Spannendes** gelesen?  (*question word*)
> *What exciting thing did you read yesterday?*

This is what happened in your example.

> Ich habe gestern **etwas so Spannendes** gelesen, **dass** ich nicht einschlafen konnte.
>
> **Was** hast du denn gestern **so Spannendes** gelesen, **dass** du nicht einschlafen konntest?